# Hibernate Search 6 More Like This

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I see that [HS5 has the MLT feature](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl-mlt). I have a HS6 project for which I need to use MLT. [HS6 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single) has no mention of **More Like This**. The [Changelog](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/changelog.txt) doesn't indicate it was dropped.

Any pointers will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "More Like This" feature hasn't been re-implemented in Hibernate Search 6 yet. I'll add a mention in the [migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/#queries-reference).

In the meantime, if you are using the Elasticsearch backend, you can write a [native predicate using JSON](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-extensions-elasticsearch-from-json) targeting the [Elasticsearch's "More Like This" query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html). I've heard it's not exactly the same, but I haven't had time to explore it yet. It might fit your use case.

If you want to see this feature again in Hibernate Search 6, including in the Lucene backend, you can get involved here: [HSEARCH-3272](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3272).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm using Lucene backend. I'm looking forward to see this feature re-implemented again.